# Palindrome from the product of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: python, palindrome

I want to find the largest palindrome that can be obtained through the multiplication of two 3-digit numbers.

I started off with a and b both being 999, and to decrement a and b with every multiplication that occurred.

```
a = 999 #Defining Variables
b = 999

for i in range (1000): 
    c= a*b                          #multiply a to b
    if int(str(c)[::-1]) == c:
        print c
    a = a-1                         #decrement the value of a
    c=a*b                           #multiply a by the decremented a
    if int(str(c)[::-1]) == c:
        print c

    b = b-1                         #decrement b so that both a and b have been decremented
```

The result has turned up 698896, 289982, 94249, 69696... with 698896 being the first number. Currently I'm still trying to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Theres no check for whether it is a one or two-digit number. Unless you're considering 010...090 as three-digits (but in this case would need extra code :] )

Comment: What awful comments! "`c= a*b #multiply a to b`"? What kind of programmer needs that line explained to them?

Comment: thank you for focusing on my comments rather than shitty code :P
I thought it would at least help to make sense of the abomination I had created.

Comment: Such comments are sometimes useful when you're starting to write code and parts of it are not obvious to you. And they are invaluable to programmers coming from INTERCAL background.

Comment: FYI this is project Euler problem #4...

Comment: @Rosh Oxymoron Thanks for making me look up INTERCAL :D

Comment: Run a debugger !

Comment: You are missing out on values

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot decrement `a` and `b` in an alternating fashion, because you're missing value pairs like a = 999 and b = 997 that way.

Try nested looping instead, starting from 999 and counting backwards.

Something like

```
def is_pal(c):
    return int(str(c)[::-1]) == c

maxpal = 0
for a in range(999, 99, -1):
    for b in range(a, 99, -1):
        prod = a * b
        if is_pal(prod) and prod > maxpal:
            maxpal = prod

print maxpal
```

EDIT: Modified lower bounds after Paul's comment.

Comment: `range(999,100,-1)` does not include 100.  Try `range(999,99,-1)`.

Comment: Paul, 100*999 is less than 698896, though. Also, x*100 ends with 00 for all natural x's, which means there is no palindrome in the set of x*100.

Comment: Also note that we trivially can halve the problem space by only checking for numbers with a >= b. Otherwise we compute both a*b and b*a which is obviously not especially useful. And that we can stop as soon as a*b <= largestPalindrome should be obvious as well - but it's harder to quantify how much that helps

Comment: @Voo: I do only check numbers where `a >= b`

Comment: @Emil: True, 100 can't possibly be a factor of a palindrome, but these code snippets get copy/pasted in all manner of mysterious ways. Better to show the correct range expression to obtain all of the 3-digit numbers than to leave it as it was (since "100 is not relevant anyway"), and leave behind an erroneous range expression that fails to remind newcomers of the frequently-mistaken off-by-one range terminator.

Comment: @jellybean Ups true, sorry my bad.

Answer (score 3):

You algorithm is wrong. You will need to test all values of a to all values of b, which can be solved by using two loops (the outer for a and the inner for b). I also suggest that you use a and b as loop indices, which simplifies the logic (makes it easier to keep in head).

Consider moving the palindrome check to it's own function as well, to make the code easier to understand.

---

I'm no Python programmer, but here's my solution in PHP:

```
function palindrome($x) {
  $x = (string) $x;  //Cast $x to string
  $len = strlen($x); //Length of $x

  //Different splitting depending on even or odd length
  if($len % 2 == 0) {
    list($pre, $suf) = str_split($x, $len/2);
  }else{
    $pre = substr($x, 0, $len/2);
    $suf = substr($x, $len/2+1);
  }

  return $pre == strrev($suf);
}

$max = array(0, 0, 0);

//Loop $a from 999 to 100, inclusive.
//Do the same over $b for EVERY $a
for($a = 999; $a >= 100; $a--) {
  for($b = 999; $b >= 100; $b--) {
    $x = $a*$b;

    if(palindrome($x)) {
      echo $a, '*', $b, ' = ', $x, "\n";
      if($x > $max[2]) {
        $max = array($a, $b, $x);
      }
    }
  }
}
echo "\nLargest result: ", $max[0], '*', $max[1], ' = ', $max[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest method is to cicle down from the biggest polindrome before maximum value 999x999=998001. 997799,996699,.. and check each if it can be divided into A and B in range 100..999. My code took 2200 cycles. Your code will take about 4K to 8K cycles.

```
Sub method3a()
iterations = 0
For a = 997 To 0 Step -1
    R = a * 1000 + Val(StrReverse(a))
    b = 999      ' R=b*s
    s = Int(R / b)
    While b >= s
        iterations = iterations + 1
        If R = b * s Then
            Debug.Print "Result=" & R & " iterations=" & iterations
            Exit Sub
        End If
        b = b - 1
        s = Int(R / b)
    Wend
Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 1000000
test = 0
while test == 0:
    i += -1
    str_i = str(i)
    if str_i[0:3] == str_i[3:][::-1]:
        for j in range(100, 1000):
            if i % j == 0:
                if i/j < 1000 and i/j > 100:
                    print('Largest Palindrome: %s = %s * %s' % (i, j, i//j))
                    test = 1
                    break
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# - solution in gist - https://gist.github.com/4496303

public class worker
    {
        public worker(){

```
    }
    public void start()
    {
        int MAX_NUMBER = 999;
        for (int Number = MAX_NUMBER; Number >= 0; Number--)
        {
            string SNumberLeft = Number.ToString();
            string SNumberRight = Reverse(Number.ToString());
            int palindromic = Convert.ToInt32(SNumberLeft + SNumberRight);

            for (int i = MAX_NUMBER; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                for (int l = MAX_NUMBER; l >= 1; l--)
                {
                    if ((i * l) - palindromic == 0)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Result :" + palindromic);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

           // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( palindromic); 
        }           

    }

    public string Reverse(String s)
    {
        char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string(arr);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it and have optimized and reduced the number of steps for search

time 0.03525909700010743

palindrome = 906609

count = 3748

i = 913

j = 993

```
from timeit import timeit

def palindrome(number):
    return str(number) == str(number)[::-1] # chek number is polindrome

def largest():
    max_num = 0
    count = 0
    ccount = 0
    ii = 0
    jj = 0
    for i in range(999, 99, -1): # from largest to smallest
        for j in range(999,  i - 1, -1): # exclude implementation j * i
            mult = i * j # multiplication
            count += 1
            if mult > max_num and palindrome(mult): # chek conditions
                max_num = mult #remember largest
                ii = i
                jj = j
                ccount = count
    return "\npalindrome = {0}\ncount = {1}\ni = {2}\nj = {3}".format(max_num, ccount, ii, jj)
print ("time", timeit('largest()', 'from __main__ import largest', number = 1))
print(largest())
```