# Why list created by code does not include values greater than 99,999 (Python)

Tags: python, list, palindrome

This code is meant to find the largest palindrome created by the product of two 3 digit numbers.

I'm sure that there are more efficient ways to solve this problem, and you're welcome to post them, but at this stage in my learning, I'm most interested in how I could edit the code that I've written to make it work correctly.

When I run this code, it correctly creates a sorted list of palindromes, but the largest number in the list is 99,999. I can't see why the list doesn't extend past this.

```
def palindromes():
    product_list=[]
    palindrome_list=[]
    for a in range(100,1000):
        for b in range(100,1000):
            product_list.append(a*b)
    for product in product_list:
        product = str(product)
        if len(product) % 2 == 0:
            if product[0]==product[5] and product[1]==product[4] and product[2]==product[3]:
                palindrome_list.append(product)
        if len(product) % 2 != 0:
            if product[0]==product[4] and product[1]==product[3]:
                palindrome_list.append(product)

    palindrome_list = sorted(set(palindrome_list))
    return palindrome_list

print(palindromes())
```

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460545/palindrome-from-the-product-of-two-3-digit-numbers?rq=1

Comment: not really, the op doesn't understand why the list is limited to 100.000 elemnts

Comment: This is helpful, but I wanted feedback on my specific code if possible. Still earning the language and I'd like to see where my code went wrong.  Is this not a good place to ask that?

Comment: maybe the question should be re-written, "why does python list cannot contain more than 99.999 elemnts.

Comment: does it write a error message when you reach 99.999 elements and after ? or does it continue silently ?

Comment: Edited. There are no errors. The list ends at 99999 when printed, and when I retrieve the last value in the list (return palindrome_list[-1]), it also returns 99999.

Comment: Oscar Lopez's answer looks really sound. Do you mean 99,999 or 999,999 items ?

Comment: @user2244527 by the way welcome in SO! I think this question is on the good site. And remember, choose a good title, show us code, and error messages. Less noise possible. And you're on the way to learn, a lot.

Comment: Thanks, Stephane! By the way, what do you mean by less noise?  The function returns no errors whatsoever, by the way :)

Comment: noise: things like 'thanks a lot', 'hi', 'best regards', 'i'm passing exams next week i want to understand this'. That's the reason why there are votes on SO: Filtering the signal from the noise. There must be good and concise questions, answered by good and precise answers. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because this part is incorrect:

```
palindrome_list.append(product)
```

You were sorting strings, not numbers - even though all the results were appearing in the list, they were being sorted as strings, and appeared in a different order than you expected. Change the above code in the two places where it appears, it should look like this:

```
palindrome_list.append(int(product))
```

Now it's easy to see what's  the largest palindrome created by the product of two 3 digit numbers (the last one in the list):

```
palindromes()[-1]
=> 906609
```

Comment: I think the OP wrote 99,999 which is 10 times less. However I think you are on the good track.

Comment: Yes, it should include all palindromes up to 998,001. It only extends up to 99,999, as Stephane mentioned.

Comment: Wow! That did the trick. It makes sense now that you've pointed it out. So simple! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @StefanieHansen phew, I'm glad that solved it :) it took me a while to realize what was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing what you told it to do.

Contrary to your assumption, **there are lots of numbers larger than 99,999 in your list**.

I have executed your code, and the first result in the list is:`101101`
which obviously is `> 99999`.

But there are other bigger like `561165` and `888888`, and they are also in your list.

In total the list contains `650` palindromes. These are the only you could generate with your start condition

you **cannot reach 999,999** because it cannot be reach in your `for` loops...

Python just did what you told it.

EDIT: Like Oscar's answer says, you should put your limit to `1001`, then the palindrome `999,999` will come to you.

Comment: I was mistaken, what OP is interested in is "the largest palindrome created by the product of two 3 digit numbers", which happens to be 906609. OP's solution was _almost_ right all along, the list was complete, it's just that the values were being sorted as strings, therefore the last one wasn't what OP expected.

Comment: I was mistaken too. However the biggest is still 999999 :-)

Comment: No, the largest possible product of two 3-digit numbers is 999*999 or 998001.  Using my revised code, I found the largest PALINDROME created by the product of two 3-digit numbers to be 906,609. This ended up being the correct answer :)

Comment: do you mean that the number 999,999 (one million minus one) is not a palindrome ?

Comment: It is a palindrome, but I am looking for the largest palindrome that can be created by multiplying two 3-digit numbers together. The largest 3-digit number is 999. Therefore, the largest possible palindrome that we can achieve must be smaller than 999*999, or 998,001. 999,999 cannot be achieved by multiplying two 3-digit numbers together.