# Determining whether a string is a Palindrome

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote the following program to determine whether a string s a palindrome using recursion.  My problem is that I am not sure how to add a print statement that tells me whether the string is a palindrome or not.  I realize that there are other codes which do the same thing, but I am trying to understand if my reasoning is correct.

```
import re
s= raw_input( " Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome ")
newstring = re.sub('\W', '', s)
newstring =newstring.lower()

def Palind(newstring):

    if newstring[0] != newstring[-1]:
        #print 'The given string is not a palindrome'
        return False 
    else: 
        s_remain = newstring[1:-1]
        if s_remain == '':
            return True
        elif len(s_remain) == 1 :
            return True
        else:
            return Palind(s_remain)


if Palind(newstring):
    print 'Yes'
else: 
    print 'No'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Comment: Should the question's title be related to printing a variable in Python?

Answer (score 1):

First, correctly indent your code, and properly lowercase the input:

```
import re
s= raw_input( " Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome ")
newstring = re.sub('\W', '', s)
newstring = newstring.lower()

def Palind(newstring):    
    if newstring[1] != newstring[-1]:
        #print 'The given string is not a palindrome'
        return False 
    else: 
        s_remain = newstring[1:-1]
        return Palind(s_remain)
```

Then actually call your function and deal with the result:

```
if Palind(newstring):
    print ('Yes')
else:
    print ('No')
```

That's how you print the result of your function..

You will have problems when you enter a palindrome though, because you never actually return true. You'll need to fix that by checking if you've gotten to the end of the string without returning false.

Comment: You may need to add commas around the `print` to ensure it works for the Python 3 folks who land here (and who breaks basic print functionality... Can you image what would have happened if `printf` broke in C99).

Comment: I'm sure Python 3 people learn that one very quickly anyway, but sure, I'll add them.

Comment: @Blorgbeard 'rodor' -> 'No'; 'a' -> IndexError: string index out of range.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler yes, I'm not purporting to have fixed every issue with the code, I'm just answering "how to add a print statement". I do mention the bug you're talking about at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I am not sure how to add the 'return True' condition in the definition of the function or to check that the function completes to the end.  I assumed  that if the string is not a palindrome, it will return False at some point.  Is that not correct?

Comment: @ShubhaRajopadhye yes, but what will happen if the string **is** a palindrome?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is roughly right, but you are missing some things.

1. The first character in a string is `string[0]` not `string[1]`, so you are comparing the wrong characters.
2. You need to call Palind() as well as `def`ining it.
3. If you correct those problems, you are taking one letter off each side of the string each time, it gets shorter and shorter - the next interesting thing that happens is you either get down to a single character or you run out of characters. You should be looking for that state.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I forgot to add the comments that would help me print the result just made that addition here.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I was able to fix it!