# Using list.reverse() on a copy changes the original

Tags: python, list

Hi I am trying to make a function that checks for Palindromes and I thought I could easily use the `list.reverse()` function but something strange is happening and I was wondering why. Here is my code:

```
x = list('hey')
x
['h', 'e', 'y']
y = x
y
['h', 'e', 'y']
y.reverse()
y
['y', 'e', 'h']
x
['y', 'e', 'h']
```

My question is why is it that when I reverse the list y it also reverses the list x?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic

Comment: @Cyber: re-hammered this one to [How can I reverse a list in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3940128)

Comment: Is it really a dupe? I feel like OP just wants to know why `x` is also modified.

Comment: this is not a question about reversing, he wants to know why hes changing both x and y at the same time

Comment: Actually [this is the proper target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Antti the target you provided asks the same question but the answers only show the person asking how to solve the problem and not exactly why its happening. The answer I got below from Vivek about the memory location was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` and `y` are refer to same memory location.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> id(x)
141910924
>>> y = x
>>> id(y)
141910924
>>> z = list(x)
>>> id(z)
141676844
>>> x.append(10)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 10]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 10]
>>> z
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

use copy and deepcopy when we want to assign list values to other variables
e.g.

```
>>> import copy
>>> x = [1,2,3, [4,5]]
>>> y = copy.copy(x)
>>> id(x)
141913324
>>> id(y)
139369964
>>> x.append(10)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 10]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
>>> x[3].append(20)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 20], 10]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 20]]
>>> z = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> z
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 20], 10]
>>> x[3].append(50)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 20, 50], 10]
>>> z
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 20], 10]
>>>
```

Comment: and the `reverse()` method mutates the list directly

Comment: adding on to it, you can use the `is` command to verify that it is indeed the same thing, `x=[1,2,3]` `y=[1,2,3]` `x is y` (this is false), `z=x` `z is x` (this is true)

Answer (score 1):

Copy `x` by value instead of by reference

```
x = list('hey')
x
['h', 'e', 'y']
y = list(x)
y
['h', 'e', 'y']
y.reverse()
y
['y', 'e', 'h']
x
['h', 'e', 'y']
```

Answer (score -2):

As Vivek has said, `y` points to the same location as `x`. To get around this, use `deepcopy` from the `copy` module:

```
import copy
x = list('hey')
y = copy.deepcopy(x)
```

This will ensure they point to separate locations and are independent.

To those who think `deepcopy` is a bad idea, I have to strongly disagree - consider this code:

```
x = [45, 54]
y = [x, 56]
z = y[::]
print z
x[0] = 1
print z
```

The output is:

```
[[45, 54], 56]
[[1, 54], 56]
```

because the shallow copy returns references to the elements of the list where possible. I am merely trying to teach the OP a generic method to create a completely independent copy - regardless of the type of object they are trying to copy.

Even self referring objects are handled by `deepcopy`:

```
>>> a = [2]
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[2, [...]]
>>> import copy
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> b
[2, [...]]
```

Comment: Actually you only need a shallow copy, such as `[::]` or just by using `reversed`

Comment: deepcopy is almost always wrong

Comment: Yes, in this simple example where the elements are all integers, `deepcopy` is unnecessary. But if you have a list with an embedded list, you need deepcopy.

Comment: Hey Niklas could you show me how to use those suggestions? I am pretty new to python and dont really know how to use extended slices.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Wow, you are just plain wrong. In fact, I would say most of the time, deepcopy is exactly what you need when you want independence. There are many cases where deepcopy is the only solution, aside from manually shallow copying the internal objects. Sure, sometimes it is unnecessary (eg for the OPs simple example).