# How to make a Palindrome Calculator in Python

Tags: python, palindrome

I am currently partway through a school project which requires me to create a python program that can read in two non-negative integers, begin and end, and **print out all of the palindromes** which occur between begin and end (inclusive). The code we have been given is this:

```
begin = int(input('Enter begin: '))
end = int(input('Enter end: '))

palindromes = 0
# Add your code here. You will want to start with a "for x in range" style loop.

print('There are', palindromes, 'palindrome(s) between', begin, 'and', end)
```

Question: How would I calculate how many palindromes are in the range of the two numbers entered (and which numbers are palindromes)?

Research: I have tried having a look at pages, this one was a good one though I (being new to python) could not make sense of it when I put it into code:
[how to check for a palindrome using python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How would I calculate how many palindromes are in the range of the two numbers entered (and which numbers are palindromes)?

Comment: Could you explain what part of the answer you cited you do not understand? You need just one loop and the code from the accepted answer.

Comment: `palindromes = len([i for i in range(begin, end+1) if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]])`. Now go and explain this to your teacher.

Comment: That is more or less what I had. The problem I was having was that the program then needs to print which numbers are palindromes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, the code I found to be the answer was this:

```
begin = int(input('Enter begin: '))
end = int(input('Enter end: '))

palindromes = palindromes = len([i for i in range(begin, end+1) if str(i) ==     str(i)[::-1]])
  for i in range(begin, end+1):
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
      print(i,'is a palindrome')

print('There are', palindromes, 'palindrome(s) between', begin, 'and', end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Palindrome number are written in the same way from right to left and from left to right : Exemple :

```
123 is not a palindrome number because its inverted representation is 321
121 is a palindrome number because its inverted representation is 121
```

and the simpliest way to do this in python is to convert the number into a string and compare it to its inverted representation (Let's say that n is a number and we want to know if it's a palindrome or not) :

```
if str(n) == str(n)[::-1]:
    print "It's a palindrome number"
```

so the solution for your problem is an if brunch inside in iteration like below :

```
print "Enter begin:"
begin = int(raw_input("> "))
print "Enter end:"
end = int(raw_input("> "))

palindromes = 0

for x in range(begin, end):
    if str(x) == str(x)[::-1]:
        palindromes += 1

print "There are %d palindrome(s) between %d and %d" % (palindromes, begin, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is school work I don't see a huge benefit in writing code for you, but here's how to break down the problem.

As the comment in your example says, you're going to want to start with a `for x in range` loop. In this case I suggest you use the version of [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) that takes both a start point and a stop point (begin, and end) -- note that this will iterate over numbers between start and stop INCLUDING start but NOT stop.

Example -- prints numbers 1 to 9 each on their own line:

```
for x in range(1, 10):
   print(x)
```

Inside your for loop you can then test to see if `x` is a palindrome. If it is you'll want to add it to a list of found palindromes. Later on you can set your `palindromes` variable to be the [length](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) of this list, and print out the contents as needed.

To find out if `x` is a palindrome, the answer you've found should help. Alternatively you can think about what a palindrome is and have a go at writing your own method. You'll want to [convert `x` to a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) before you start, and then it's just a case of comparing the first and last halves of the string, and there are a few interesting ways of doing this :)

Here are two options you could try:

1) Use *slicing* to split the string in half (ignoring the middle character if there is an odd number of characters). [Reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python) ONE half of the string, and then compare it with the other half; if they are the same then it's a palindrome.

2) Use another `for` loop with a `start` of 0 and a `stop` of half the length (rounded down to the nearest whole number). Inside the loop take *slices* of both ends of the string and compare them.

Example (where x is the loop counter and currently has a value of 0).

> > > string = 'abcd'
> > >       string[0+x]
> > >       'a'
> > >       string[-(1+x)]
> > >       'd'

For both of these answers you'll want to look at how to slice a string if you're not already familiar with this. There's some helpful examples [in this Python introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

A palindrome is a number which when written reversed is same as the original number. For example, 1234321 is a palindrome.

So, to check this, all you have to do is check if the reverse of the number is the same as original.

Here's the code.

```
begin = int(input('Enter begin:'))
end = int(input('Enter end:'))

palindromes = 0

for i in range(begin, end+1, 1):
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:  #Here I convert the int to string and check if t matches the reverse
       palindromes += 1
       print i
print "Total number of palindromes = ",palindromes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Palindrome Number Calculator

Palindrome = False
Test = 0
newInt = 0

myInt = int(input("Enter a number "))
myIntReversed = int(str(myInt)[::-1])

if myInt == myIntReversed:
    print("Your number is a palindrome")
    Palindrome = True
    exit()

while Palindrome == False:

    myInt += myIntReversed

    Test += 1

    myIntReversed = int(str(myInt)[::-1])

    if myInt == myIntReversed:
        print("Palindrome")
        print(myInt)
        Palindrome = True

exit()
```

If you use pycharm then you can use the debug feature to see what test number the computer is at. I am not printing this number so the program runs faster. Try to see if your program can see what the palindrome of 196 is :)