# How to test if a list of strings are palindromes using list comprehension or slicing?

Tags: python, string, palindrome

I am trying to test if a list of strings are palindromes using list comprehension or slicing. I converted `str1` to list using `word_list=str1.split()`. However, the palindrome test,

```
word=[w for w in word_list if w[0:9:1]==w[0:9:1][::-1]]
```

works for only the first word. Since the words have different lengths, I am wondering if there are concise way of writing the code without using common loops?

```
str1='avallava si padre emirime'
```

Comment: `word=[w for w in word_list if w==w[::-1]]` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Comment: This may not be the best way of testing for palindromes, but I can't reproduce your issue. Running your code I get `word == ['avallava', 'emirime']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chris_Rands answer solved the problem.
`word=[w for w in word_list if w==w[::-1]]`

Answer (score 1):

The line below iterates through word_list, keeps the words which are palindromes and stores them as a list.

`palindromes = [w for w in word_list if w == w[::-1]]`

If `world_list = ['avallava', 'si', 'padre', 'emirime']`,

then `palindromes = ['avallava', 'emirime']`

Answer (score 0):

a=['aba','abc','lil','ozx']
b=[]
for i in a:
if i==i[::-1]:
b.append(i)

print(b)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).