# To check whether palindrome or not

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, palindrome

On compilation of this code it shows `None` as Output

```
list = ["malayalam"]
reverse_list = list.reverse()
print(reverse_list)
while list == reverse_list:
    print('the answer is palindrome')
```

Comment: Are you running this in REPL?

Comment: Do you want to check if the _list_ is palindromic?  Or that it _contains_ palindromes?  Or don't you actually need a list and are mistaken?

Comment: As stated by @xtofl, please state your requirements properly. Also, I request all the people writing an answer to this question, to wait for some time and allow the OP to explain his problem more briefly.

Answer (score 1):

reverse() mutates the original list and doesn't return a new one.
so  reverse_list=list.reverse() makes reverse_list None.

Here's an answer you might want to check out
[How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong reverse function in python try this one

```
def is_palindrome1(st):
    ln = len(st)
    for i in range(ln//2):
        if st[i] != st[ln - 1 - i]:
            return False
    return True

def is_palindrome2(st):
    lst=list("malayalam")
    reversed_list=list(reversed(lst))
    return lst == reversed_list

def is_palindrome3(st):
    p1 = st[:len(st)//2]
    p2 = st[(len(st)+1)//2:]
    return p1 == p2

lst = "malayalam"

if is_palindrome1(lst):
    print('the answer is palindrome')
else:
    print('not palindrome')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead reverse the string itself

Use the following

```
>>> a = "Malayalam"
>>> rev = a[::-1]
>>> if a == rev:
>>>   print("palindrome")
>>> else:
>>>   print("Not a palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why it says None ?**

Here's an example,

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> mylist
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> mylist.reverse()
None

>>> mylist
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

As you can see, calling mylist.reverse() returned None, but modified the original list object. This implementation was chosen deliberately by the developers of the Python standard library:

> The reverse() method modifies the sequence in place for economy of space when reversing a large sequence. To remind users that it operates by side effect, it does not return the reversed sequence. [Source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#mutable-sequence-types)

So in your case it should print **None**, and since **list == reverse_list** is evaluated to **false** nothing other than the previous will print. Why is explained earlier.

***Hope you want to check a word is palindrome or not***, if so you don't need a list for that. Below solution uses some inbuilt functions to achieve that.

```
word = "malayalam"
rev = ''.join(reversed(word))

if (word == rev):
    print('the answer is palindrome')
else:
    print('the answer is not a palindrome')
```

[See this working example](https://repl.it/repls/WellgroomedDevotedFieldspaniel)