# Finding a string whose reverse is also present in the sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the string in a sentence whose reverse is also present in the same sentence and return that string.

Suppose the sentence is:

> illusion never changed into something real wide awake and i can see the perfect sky ees torn you are a little late I'm already torn

Here we can see that `"see"` has a reverse present as `"ees"`

So the output should be `"see"`

Please guide me how to do that.

Comment: Look for instance at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic

Comment: @Rakesh, this question is not a duplicate, since the question you are referring to resolves just a small part of the problem, but the bigger problem is finding all palindromes within the string!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
mystr = "illusion never changed into something real wide awake and i can see the perfect sky ees torn you are a little late I'm already torn"

def reverse(word):
    letter = list(word)
    length = len(letter)
    y = []
    for x,w in enumerate(letter):
        y.append("".join(letter[(length-1)-x]))
    return("".join(yy for yy in y))


words = mystr.split()
for word in words:
    if (reverse(word)) in words and len(word) > 1:   # len(word)>1 is for ignoring a word that contains only one letter, e.g. 'I' and 'a'.
        print ("'" + word + "' is the reverse of '" + reverse(word) + "'")
```

Output:

```
'see' is the reverse of 'ees'
'ees' is the reverse of 'see'
```

You can also try the simpler one as suggested by @Nuhman.

```
mystr = "illusion never changed into something real wide awake and i can see the perfect sky ees torn you are a little late I'm already torn"

words = mystr.split()
for word in words:
    if word[::-1] in words and len(word) > 1:
        print ("'" + word + "' is the reverse of '" + reverse(word) + "'")
```

Output:

```
'see' is the reverse of 'ees'
'ees' is the reverse of 'see'
```

Comment: It's easier to just use `word[::-1]` to reverse. Also you could add a check whether `len(word) > 1`.

Comment: @Nuhman, Yes you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `word[::-1]` to reverse the word and if reverse is present in list of words store it another `list`.

```
hello = "illusion never changed into something real wide awake and i can see the perfect sky ees torn you are a little late I'm already torn"

words = hello.split(" ")

reverse_words = []
for word in words:
    if word[::-1] in words and len(word)>1 and word[::-1] not in reverse_words:
        reverse_words.append(word)

print(reverse_words)
```

Output:

```
['see']
```