# Check for palindrome

Tags: python, boolean, palindrome

This is a question from one exam. Lets say we have a function, def palindrome (s), and we call it. If it is a palindrome, the function should return True.

```
def palindrome(s):
    ...
palindrome("radar")
```

In order to check if it is a palindrome, i tried to reverse the string in order to see if it was the same. I used `s.find(s[::-1])`.

The alternatives from the exam was:

```
return  bool(s.find(s[::-1]))
return  not(bool(s.find(s[::-1]
```

I don't understand the difference between these two alternatives, can someone explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Answer (score 1):

The equality operator '==' returns True or False

```
def palindrome(s):
    reverse_str = s[::-1]
    return s == reverse_str

palindrome("radar")
```

True

The **find**() method finds the first occurrence of the specified value or returns -1 if the value is not found.

```
def palindrome(s):
    reverse_str = s[::-1]
    return s.find(reverse_str)

palindrome("radar")
```

0

Answer (score 0):

## Solution #1

```
return  bool(s.find(s[::-1]))
```

This is just the same as your solution. The only difference is it gets casted to a boolean type.

> The bool() method converts a value to Boolean (True or False) using
>   the standard truth testing procedure.

## Solution #2

```
return  not(bool(s.find(s[::-1]))
```

Just the same as previous solution but the result gets flipped. Why flip it? When found the result will be 0, when not found the result will be -1. This results in False (0) and True(-1). So it's weird that when found it gives False and when not found it gives True. That's why it's flipped.