# "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, runtime-error

**Here is the condition :** To take an integer and return true if it is symmetrical.
*A number is symmetrical if it's the same forwards and backwards*.

**The code:**

```
def is_symmetrical(num):
number_list = list(num)
forwardList = []
backwardList = []
for num in number_list:
    forwardList.append(num)
    buffer = letter
    backwardList.append(num- num*2)
if forwardList == backwardList:
    return True
else :
    return False
```

Comment: You get this error because, as the message says, an 'int' object is not iterable. `list('123')` will work, `list(123)` not.

Comment: don't you mean list(str(num))? an integer sure isn't iterable...

Comment: Also, you should include all the information you have about an error instead of expecting people to work it out themselves

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Answer (score 1):

An int object isn’t iterable, so you have to convert the input to `str` format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the digits from the number in a list of ints, you could go for:

```py
number_list = [int(num / (10 ** idx)) % 10 for idx in range(len(str(num))-1, -1, -1)]
```

Comment: Could you break that up and explain that a bit? It's very confusing to look at a glance.