# Python: How to write a function for palindrome

Tags: python

I try to write a function for palindrome.below is my code

```
def ispalindrome(string):
    if len(string) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        if string[0] == string[-1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Only one thing I don't understand is one of my results it says "ispalindrome('123321') should return False", and my result for this one is true. I don't know what to do now. Anyone can help me correct this?

Comment: A very basic google search and this answer would have been easy to find. Check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-check-string-palindrome-not/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Answer (score 1):

You just check the first and the last element, you didn't check the characther in the middle

```
def ispalindrome(x):
    if len(x) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        n = len(x)
        for i in range(n//2):
            if x[i] != x[n-1-i]:
                return False
        return True
```

Also, "123321" is indeed a palindrome.