# Determining if a number is a palindrome

Tags: python

```
#WAP to check given number is Armstrong or not, (done)
#if it is Armstrong then print reverse of that number,  (done)
#if it is not Armstrong then check it is Palindrome or not.   (problem)

no=int(input("Enter your number:"))
temp=no
arm=0
rev=0
while(no>0):
    rem=no%10
    cube=rem*rem*rem
    arm=arm+cube
    no=no//10

if(temp==arm):
    while (temp> 0):
        rem = temp % 10
        rev = (rev * 10) + rem
        temp = temp // 10
    print("Reverse is:", rev)

elif(temp!=arm):
    while (temp > 0):
        rem = temp % 10
        rev = rev * 10 + rem
        temp = temp // 10

if(rev==temp):
    print("It's a palindrome.")

else:
    print("It's not a palindrome.")
```

I can't find out the problem with the "check if it is a palindrome" part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to check if number is palindrome or not

```
if str(temp)==str(temp)[::-1]:
    print("Number is palindrome")
else:
    print("Not palindrome")
```

Comment: thank you Sai! this solved. I wonder could you give a further elaboration on the line "if str(temp)==str(temp)[::-1]:"

Comment: `[a,b,c]` is indexing in python. Similar to a for loop in any language - `for(int i=a;i<b;i+=c)`. `[::-1]` means from the start of the string to end of string with the step size `-1`. It means it reads the index in reverse order - `mad[::-1]` gives `dam`. So, a palindrome like `madam` gives `madam`. Therefore, comparing both of them tells, if a given string is palindrome or not. `str(temp)` is typecasting an integer to string

Comment: Ok clear! Thank you pal. God bless!:)

Answer (score 1):

In your code to check for palindrome, you are repeatedly dividing your `temp` value by 10, but your condition is for `temp>0` which will never be reached, as repeated division by 10 will never result in a negative number. So, you should change your condition to `while(temp>=1)`.

Also, you should compare the final value of `rev` to `no` instead of with `temp`.
So if you change your final condition to `if(rev==no):` it should work. This is because your temp keeps getting modified in your loop to check for palindrome, whereas you want to compare your final rev with the original number.

Comment: Hi Arijit, thank you for your comment but unfortunately I tried and that doesn't work....  the codes still failed to check palindrome.