# Is this a correct way to get palindrome? I got the result but m not sure

Tags: python, palindrome

I tried to strip the "Never Odd or Even" to remove the whitespaces but it didn't worked or i was not doing it correctly. 
So I tried to split the string into list and then join them such that all the whitespace would be removed.

**here is the code :**

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    lowerinput = input_string.lower()
    splitinginput = lowerinput.split()
    for new_string in lowerinput:
        if lowerinput[0] == lowerinput[-1]:
            new = new_string.join(splitinginput)
            reverse_string = new_string[::-1]
    if new_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

Sorry i am new and this question could be little naive but i would love to know your feedback..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're not changing the letters to lowercase, so for example, `"nN"`would yield false in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for palindrome without using loops

1. Remove all white spaces in the input string.
2. Convert the string to lower case.
3. Compare the string with its reverse.
4. return the output.

```py
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    string = input_string.replace(" ", "").lower()
    rev_str = string[::-1]

    return string == rev_str

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even"))
print(is_palindrome("abc"))
print(is_palindrome("kayak"))
```

output:

```
True
False
True
```

Comment: This is a much better way
thanks!! @Sidharth

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
   input_string = input_string.lower()
   input_string = "".join(input_string.split())
   reverse_string = input_string[::-1]
   if input_string == reverse_string:
      return True
   else:
      return False
print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```