# Checking if number is palindrome always returns false

Tags: python-3.x, function, numbers, palindrome

I'm trying to check if integer number is palindrome but my code always returns false.

```
def checkPalindrome(num):
    rev = 0
    while num != 0:
        d = num % 10
        rev = (rev * 10) + d
        num = num // 10
    print(rev)
    if num==rev:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(checkPalindrome(1))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Comment: You may want to add `print(num)` next to `print(rev)`... Otherwise just copy-paste existing solutions for the same problem.

Comment: Note that normally you should not tag question with two languages - the code shown in the post does not look like BASIC - are you looking to translate the code to BASIC? Also make sure to clarify why this is Python 3 specific - usually questions should be tagged with just "python" unless there is significant difference between versions and the question is specifically about 3.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you wrote

```
def checkPalindrome(num):
    rev = 0
    while num != 0:
    d = num % 10
    rev = (rev * 10) + d
    num = num // 10
    print(rev)
    if num==rev:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

In this line `num = num // 10` `num` is replaced by `num/10` and in next `if` condition you are checking `num==rev` which is always false. So how many times you give a value it always gives you false.

So if you store `num` in a `temporary variable` i.e, `tempVariable=num` so that you when you reverse the `num` you can check the original value with `tempVariable` and then do `num = num // 10` and in next `if` condition you can check `tempVariable==rev` which will give you correct result.

Following code will give you correct result for numbers

```
def checkPalindrome(num):
    tempVariable = num
    rev = 0
    while num != 0:
        d = num % 10
        rev = (rev * 10) + d
        num = num // 10
    if tempVariable == rev:
        return True
    else:
        return False

num = int(input())
isPalindrome = checkPalindrome(num)
if (isPalindrome):
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```