# How do check for a palindrome in Python?

Tags: python

I am given word and I have to check if the word is a palindrome. My program works well until I play around with the case of the word.

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    reversedWord = word[::-1]
    palindrome = true
    for n in range(len(word)):
        if(word[n] != reversedWord[i])
            palindrome = false
    return palindrome
```

I tried the below code and it works well if I feed the function the word "mom", however it fails when I give it the same word but with a different case "Mom"

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    reversedWord = word[::-1]
    palindrome = true
    for n in range(len(word)):
        if(word[n] != reversedWord[i])
            palindrome = false
    return palindrome
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Comment: Because `"Mom" != "moM"`.

Comment: Also, this is not a valid python.

Answer (score 1):

You are already reversing the string. Just return reversedWord.lower() == word.lower() instead of checking character by character.

Answer (score 1):

You need to normalise the string to either upper- or lower-case.

```
def isPalindrome(word):
  word = word.lower()
  return word == word[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest form to this is where you use Ternary operator and Python String lower() method as given below:

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    return True if (word.lower() == word[::-1].lower()) else False
```

Comment: You don't need a ternary operator here. `return True if x else False` is the same as `return x`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to compare the lowercase version of the word to its reversed version. There is a function in Python that transforms a String to all-lowercase. Search for it and try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

The hex values ​​of m and M in ascii table are different from each other.
Since these values ​​are different in logic comparison, the result will be not a polydrome.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your word into lowercase (or uppercase) and then check if the reversed if it is a palindrome.

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return True if word == word[::-1] else False
```

`isPalindrom("Mom")` returns `True`

Comment: `return word == word[::-1]` is equivalent to `return True if word == word[::-1] else False`