# Complexity of finding all substrings that are palindromes

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I have a string and I want to find all its substrings that are equal to their inverse.

For example, there are four substrings in "ababa", which is equal to its inverse:

- "aba" (index 1 to 3)
- "bab" (index 2 to 4)
- "aba" (index 3 to 5)
- "ababa" (index 1 to 5)

This is my simple code that solves the problem in o(n^3).

```
string = str(input())
n = len(string)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 2, n + 1):
        if string[i:j] == string[i:j][::-1]:
            print(i + 1, j)
```

I want to know if this problem can be solved in linear time.

If not, what is the best algorithm for this problem?

Comment: I don't see a reason why this has been voted to close. The question is perfectly fine.

Comment: "equal to their inverse" - Those are called *palindromes* :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Comment: Please define "best". Best performing? Most elegant? You can [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for more tips like how to write a good title. I've clarified the title for you, but if you're not happy with it, you can change it further ofc.

Comment: Linear time is clearly impossible.  Consider a string in which all the characters are the same - all substrings are palindromic, and there's O(n²) of them...

Comment: @ti7, This question is not a duplicate as the question is not "how to determine if a string is a palindrome", but rather "Is the complexity of finding all substrings that are palindromes less than O(N^3)"?

Comment: @ti7 That does _not_ answer their question.

Comment: Check out--[Manacher's Algorithm - Finding all sub-palindromes in O(N)](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/manacher.html)

Comment: See also: [Finding the Longest Palindromic Substrings in Linear Time](https://www.akalin.com/longest-palindrome-linear-time). (NB: the code examples are Python2, so just replace `xrange` with `range`).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to use is a Manacher's algorithm. It's exactly for this problem, and is initially used to find the longest palindrome in a string. I suggest you try this:

1. Preprocess the input string to handle even-length palindromes.
2. Initialize an array to store the length of the palindrome centered at each position.
3. Traverse the string, updating the palindrome lengths using the information from already processed positions.
4. Keep track of the longest palindrome and its center.

Comment: No. OP wants to print all substrings. So, Manacher's algorithm won't do any good. The overall time complexity is still going to remain O(n^2). As a matter of fact, Manacher's  would make the code look even more complicated.