# Error with my code that checks if a number is a palindrome

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, palindrome

This is my code that checks if a number is a palindrome.

```
class Solution(object):
    def isPalindrome(self, x):
        string = str(x)
        idx = 0
        # if the number is even; 
        if (x % 2) == 0:
            for i in range (1, len(string)/2 + 1):
                if string[i - 1] == string[len(string) - i]:
                    idx += 1 
            if idx == len(string)/2: 
                return True
        #if the number is odd: 
        else: 
            if len(string) > 2: 
                for i in range(1, (len(string)-1)/2 + 1):
                    if string[i - 1] == string[len(string) - i]:
                        idx += 1
                if idx == (len(string)-1)/2:
                    return True
            elif len(string) == 2: 
                if string[0] == string[1]: 
                    return True
            else: 
                return True
```

But, why doesn't my code work when x = 1000030001? My program thinks that 1000030001 is a palindrome. Can anybody tell me where my code is incorrect?

I already tried to plug in every value manually to debug, and it shows that it will return False, even though when I run the program it returns True.

Comment: Given that you wrote it, step 1 is for you to step through your code. Start with 1000030001 and literally run this code by hand, which shouldn't take particularly long. (that said, this is a _lot_ of code if you just want to check whether a number is a palindrome. You just need to check if the first and last digit are the same, then remove them and run the same check until you're either left with one or zero digts to check)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] when asking s question. Saying "I tried to plug in manually" and "my program thinks" is not enough to understand what you tried. BTW there are many errors in the code and using a debugger to go line by line is the way to understand them.

Comment: This is a very complicated approach. If you convert the number to a String you can check for a palindrome in one simple expression: `if num_str == num_str[::-1]:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Answer (score 3):

The issue in regards to code is that you are checking if the number is even or not instead of the length of that number being even or odd.

you could simply do

```
class Solution():
    def isPalindrome(x):
        string = str(x)
        for i in range(len(string) // 2):
            if string[i] != string[-i - 1]:
                return False
        return True
```

and now if you run you will get False for 1000030001

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
def is_palindrome(x):
    return str(x) == str(x)[::-1]
```