# Finding the largest palindrome of the product of two 3-digit numbers in Python

Tags: python, palindrome

So the challenge I'm trying to solve is to find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers. I'm new to Python and so my code is not elegant or refracted yet, but there is a logical error that I can't seem to find.

```
def ispalindrome(n):
    rev_n = str(n)[::-1]
    if n == rev_n:
        return True
    else:
        return False


first_num = 100
second_num = 100
mylist=[]
while first_num < 1000:
    while second_num < 1000:
        item = first_num * second_num
        mylist.append(item)
        second_num += 1
    second_num = 100
    first_num +=1
# print (mylist)
num_as_string = []
for i in mylist:
    i = str(i)
    num_as_string.append(i)
print("Total products of two 3-digit numbers: {}").format(len(num_as_string))
print("-----------------------------------------------------")

def convert_to_num_list(string_list):
    new_num_list = []
    item = int(string_list)
    new_num_list.append(item)
    return new_num_list



palindrome_list = []

for j in num_as_string:
    if ispalindrome(j) == True:
        palindrome_list.append(j)
        palindrome_list.sort()
        # print(palindrome_list)
        x = convert_to_num_list(j)
        largest_palindrome = max(x)

print("Total palindroms of product of two 3-digit numers: {}").format(len(palindrome_list))

print("Largest palindrome = {}").format(largest_palindrome)
```

The problem is that I'm getting the largest palindrome as 580085, which is 995*583 but is NOT the largest palindrome. I believe the largest palindrome is 906609, which is 993*913, but my code is not finding this. Can anyone help me with the flaw in my logic?

Comment: if you want the largest number formed, why to start from 100 and go up to 1000? If you start from 999 and go to 100 (one unit in each counter at a time), you can stop searching as soon as you get the first palindrome.

Comment: @jsbueno Thank you. That definitely sounds like the most efficient way to get this result.

Comment: @jsbueno That approach certainly didn't occur to me. It is clearly efficient, and if I were working with 9 million numbers rather than 900 I would be glad of the suggestion. But I suspect it might also be hard to get right.

Comment: The problems will soon become harder, and even earlier problems may come back with vastly different numbers, where we have to rethink strategies. Have fun with Project Euler! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Palindrome from the product of two 3-digit numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460545/palindrome-from-the-product-of-two-3-digit-numbers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does a lot of unnecessary conversion between numbers and strings, which made the error hard to find. The only place in the code that needs a string representation is when determining if the number is a palindrome or not. So that should be the only place that the code does the conversion.

The logic error is in your function `convert_to_num_list()`. It takes a string representation of *one* number and returns a 1-list containing that number. So, `"123321"` gets returned as `[123321]`. You then take the `max()` of that 1-list, which is always the value that was passed to `convert_to_num_list()`. So the code never keeps the largest value because if a smaller value comes in later it will be overwritten. The code reports `995*583` as the largest because it comes in later than `993*913`, which in turn is because `995` > `993`.

You can fix that error with an `if` statement, but the program is overcomplicated and may well contain other bugs. I recommend reducing the code to the essential task of producing the largest palindrome, without printing out the intermediate results, because the simpler the code the easier it is to see a logic error.

```
def ispalindrome(n):
    return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]

mylist=[]
for first_num in range(100,1000):
    for second_num in range(100,1000):
        item = first_num*second_num
        if ispalindrome(item):
            mylist.append(item)
print(max(mylist))
```

This gives your expected answer:

```
906609
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function for finding the largest palindrome of the product of two 3-digit numbers that I found in stackoverflow.

Link to what i found- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7460573

```
def is_pal(c):
       return int(str(c)[::-1]) == c

   maxpal = 0
   for a in range(999, 99, -1):
       for b in range(a, 99, -1):
           prod = a * b
           if is_pal(prod) and prod > maxpal:
               maxpal = prod

   print maxpal
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n1=999
n2=999
k=0
sl=[]
while n1>1:
  count=n1
  while count>=1:
    result=n1*count
    res=str(result)
    res1=res[::-1]
    if (res==res1):
      sl.insert(k,result)
      k+=1
    count=count-1
  n1=n1-1
print("largest pelindrom of 3 digit product is is %d" %(max(sl)))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There's already an accepted answer so you should explain in a few words how your answer is different from the already accepted answer.

Comment: Since we have to find largest 3 digit product so i have started multiplying  higher digit first to execute faster so i start with n1=n2=999 and store n1 temporarily in count then multiplied n2 with count. I have used to loops so that the program will not miss any multiplication and the multiplication result stored in res by converting it into string so that we can easily check whether this string is palindrome or not.And  if palindrome then stored in list and lasty i have printed max using max function. I have executed both code any my code took around 4-5 sec while other code taking 5-6 sec.

Comment: The intent of the original answer was not to provide a better algorithm but to explain to the OP where his logic error was. Therefore it preserves as much of the original code (algorithm, variable names, and general structure) as was consistent with getting the correct result from a readable program. Your algorithm is 40% more efficient (499,499 palindrome checks instead of 810,000) and it would be faster still if if did `sl.append(result)` instead of `sl.insert(k,result)`, or used a set. But it doesn't answer the question *Can anyone help me with the flaw in my logic?*

Comment: Hi boar Guess  first_num in range(100,1000):
    for second_num in range(100,1000)  is the flaw 1st time first_num 100 and when it go  to inner loop second_num 100 then 101 and so on so it multiply 100*101 again when inner loop end then first_num=101 and when it comes to the inner loop second_num=100 so it multiply 101*100 so lot of luplicate value even my code time also reduced if I use n1>100  and n2>100 that I realized later

Answer (score 1):

```
palin=[]

for a in (range(1,1000)):
    for b in (range(1,1000)):
        d = a*b
        d=str(d)
        if len(d)>5: 
            if d[0]==d[5]:
                    if d[1]==d[4]:
                        if d[2]==d[3]:
                            palin.append(d)
palin.sort()
print(palin[len(palin)-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using List comprehension can reduce the lines of code but i'll give an alternate option so that it's more readable.

```
List_of_palindromes = [i*j for i in range(100,1000) for j in range(i,1000) if str(i*j)==str(i*j)[::-1]]
print(max(List_of_palindromes))
```

> More Readable form

```
List_of_palindromes = []
for i in range(100,1000):
    for j in range(100,1000):
        if str(i*j)==str(i*j)[::-1]:
            List_of_palindromes.append(i*j)
print(max(List_of_palindromes))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out..!
This can be shortened but its better understandable this way(for beginners).

```
    l = list(range(100, 1000))
    m = list(range(100, 1000))
    prod_max = 0

    def is_palindrome(num):
      temp = num
      rev=0
      while num > 0:
        div = num%10
        rev = rev*10 + div
        num = num //10
        if rev == temp:
          return True
        else:
          return False

    for i in range(len(l)):
      for j in range(len(m)):
        prod = l[i]*m[j]
        if is_palindrome(prod) == True:
          if prod > prod_max:
            prod_max = prod
            num1 = l[i]
            num2 = m[j]
    print(f'{prod_max} the product of {num1} and {num2} is a palindrome')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. There are several answers to the question, so could you please explain in a few words how your answer is different from others?