# Fastest algorithm to find the largest palindrome that is the product of 2 numbers with the same number of digits

Tags: python, palindrome

How do I make this code run in under 30s to find the largest palindrome that is the product of 2 numbers with the same number of digits?

```
def palindrome(maxInt):
    pa=[]
    for x in range(maxInt,0,-1):
        for y in range(maxInt,0,-1):
            num=x*y
            if str(num) == str(num)[::-1]:
                pa.append(num)
    return max(pa)
```

`maxInt` is the largest number with the specified digits. For example if you want a palindrome that is a multiple of 2 3-digit numbers you `maxInt` would be 999. If you want the largest palindrome that is a multiple of 2 4-digit numbers `maxInt` would be 9999. etc.

If `maxInt = 9`, it should output 9.

If `maxInt = 99`, it should output 9009.

So if `maxInt = 999`, the programme should output 906609.

How do I make it return 99000099 for `maxInt=9999` in under 30s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the largest palindrome of the product of two 3-digit numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224732/finding-the-largest-palindrome-of-the-product-of-two-3-digit-numbers-in-python)

Comment: Heh. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-palindrome-product-two-n-digit-numbers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It gets faster if you fix that `x>=y`, so `99*91` and `91*99` will not be tested and found separately
2. When a palindrome is found, the inner loop can exit (as it is counting downwards, all palindromes it may find for the same `x` are certainly smaller than the "current" one)
3. If the current product is smaller than the current maximum, the inner loop can also exit
4. If `x*x` is smaller than the current maximum, the outer loop can exit too

---

```
def palindrome(maxInt):
    maxpal=0
    for x in range(maxInt,0,-1):
        if x*x<maxpal:                         # 4.
            break
        for y in range(x,0,-1):                # 1.
            num=x*y
            if num<maxpal:                     # 3.
                break
            if str(num) == str(num)[::-1]:
                maxpal=num
                break                          # 2.
    return maxpal
```

(Of course **`3.`** could be in the range, `for y in range(x,maxpal//x,-1):` perhaps)

5. Strictly said, it should only check `y`-s having the same number of digits as `x`, which was not addressed yet, but `**` and a downwards-rounded `log10()` can do that after all.

My current complete code:

```
import math,time

def palindrome(maxInt):
    maxpal=0
    for x in range(maxInt,0,-1):
        if x*x<maxpal:                                                     # 4.
            break
        for y in range(x,max(maxpal//x,10**int(math.log10(x))-1),-1):      # 1. 3. 5.
            num=x*y
            if str(num) == str(num)[::-1]:
                maxpal=num
                break                                                      # 2.
    return maxpal

start=time.time()
print(palindrome(9))
print(palindrome(99))
print(palindrome(999))
print(palindrome(9999))
print(palindrome(99999))
print(palindrome(999999))
print("%d seconds" % (time.time()-start))
```

Example output:

> ```
> 9
> 9009
> 906609
> 99000099
> 9966006699
> 999000000999
> 0.731034 seconds
> ```

Comment: @YEpd I think it is better now

Comment: @AKX, that is cheating :-)

Comment: Keep a rolling maximum, if `num < rollingMax` then you can skip the rest of the `y`'s and move on to the next x.
EDIT: you did this fix as I was typing it, damn it!

Comment: @tevemadar I call it a quirk of SO's formatting ;) The other option is to use fenced code blocks.

Comment: ah, answer updated before i post anything. Oh well, the running check improves it quite a bit

Comment: @tevemadar Check this execution time comparison: http://ideone.com/zbVgSF

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz, yes, I remember. Palindromes with even number of digits are multiples of 11. Add the explanation and you will have my upvote.

Comment: @tevemadar I will add the explanation soon. Right now I am a little busy.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount of computation in a number of ways.  The following completes in under 4s on my laptop:

```
def palindrome(maxInt):
    pa = 0
    for x in range(maxInt, 0, -1):
        for y in range(maxInt, x, -1):
            num = x*y
            if num > pa:
                str_num = str(num)
                if str_num == str_num[::-1]:
                  pa = num
    return pa

print(palindrome(9999))
```

1. Since multiplication is commutative, we don't need to look at both, say, `21*34` and `34*21`.  Hence the inner loop can stop at `x` rather than go all the way down to `0`.  This halves the execution time.
2. String operations are expensive.  If, having computed the product, we see that it's not larger than the largest palindrome we've seen so far, there's no point in even checking whether it is a palindrome itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fast and efficient algorithm (based on mathematical calculations):

```
def palindrome(maxInt):
    largest_palindrome = 9
    digit_count = len(str(maxInt))
    a = maxInt
    while a >= 10**(digit_count-1):
        if a % 11 == 0:
            b = maxInt
            divided_by = 1
        else:
            b = maxInt - maxInt % 11
            divided_by = 11

        while b >= a:
            if a * b <= largest_palindrome:
                break
            prod = a * b
            str_num = str(prod)
            if str_num == str_num[::-1]:
                largest_palindrome = prod

            b = b - divided_by
        a = a - 1
    return largest_palindrome
```

It gives the result in a fraction of a second. You can also check the [benchmark result](http://ideone.com/zbVgSF) with @tevemadar version. *(I will add an explanation of the algorithm later.)*