# How can I make my code loop back to the beginning when I call the function multi()?

Tags: python-3.x, palindrome

#### A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

#### Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

```
a = 999
c = 999

def multi():
    global a
    a = a - 1
    global c
    c = 999

for i in range(99, 1000):
    n = a * c
    c -= 1
    print('%s * %s = %s.' % (a, c, n))
    if str(n)[0] == str(n)[-1] and str(n)[1] == str(n)[-2] and str(n)[2] == str(n)[-3]:
        print('%s * %s = %s, which is a palindrome!' % (a, c, n))
    if c == 99:
        multi()
print('Done.')
```

This is my code so far for project euler #4. I'm having trouble making it go back to the beginning after I call the function multi(). I'm still a newbie on this whole thing so forget me if anything is wrong with it. The code seems to work, just not as intended. this is the last few line of the output:

> 999 * 102 = 102897. 999 * 101 = 101898. 999 * 100 = 100899. 999 * 99 =
> 99900. 998 * 998 = 997002. Done.

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Is the `for` loop inside of `multi`? Or is `multi` only those 4 lines?

Comment: I'd go with a different design though. A nested for loop would make much more sense. `for a in range(100, 1000): for c in range(100, 1000): n = a * c` (but split over multiple lines).

Comment: The for loop is not inside the function multi(), both are with 0 indentation. That is a smart approach, I might try it now see how it goes haha. This problem is driving me crazy

Comment: Also, to check if the string is a palindrome, using another loop would make more sense. Something like `str_n = str(n); for i in range(len(str_n)): if str_n[i] != str_n[0 - i]: (Not a palindrome)`.

Comment: Or, the very idiomatic, but more complex `all(f == l for f, l in zip(str_n, reversed(str_n)))`

Comment: Damn this last one is still too advanced for me :P

Comment: Refer to this for more clarification [palindrome-from-the-product-of-two-3-digit-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460545/palindrome-from-the-product-of-two-3-digit-numbers)

Comment: But thanks to your comment I've changed the code which it is just about to finish running but I guess it's corret. I'm now using a nested for loop and a palindrome list to put the highest number which is a palindrome is that list so the last number in it should be the highest.

Comment: Like last one - but it's too exotic (complex for the beginner? ...)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help: (as @Carcigenicate suggested)

```py
n = 0

# this is for 3-digit

for a in range(999, 900, -1):
    for b in range(a, 900, -1):
        x = a * b
        if x > n:
            sab = str(a*b)
            if sab == sab[::-1]:
                n = a * b
                #print(n)

print(n)   # 906609 == 993 * 913
```

Comment: I know what [:-1] means but never saw it used like [::-1] before. Gotta search this one up haha. 
Anyway, the answer you provided to use a nested for loop was genius and it worked perfectly. The program took about 2min to run so many number but printed the correct answer right after so thanks for that!

I cant post the new code here because it exceeds the max number of characters but It is very good to see it working.

Comment: @fmagesty [::-1] reverses the sequence (the third element in a slice is the step, and a negative step is backwards). Note though, [::-1] should be avoided if possible. It creates a full copy of the list, which requires an iteration of it, then `==` needs to do potentially another full iteration. It's fine for non-performance sensitive code, but it's relatively expensive.

Comment: @fmagesty - just try to run this little program 100 times, and total time is 0.7 sec.  Not sure why yours is 2min?  Do you still  just try to find 'the Largest Palindromic Number' or changin something afterwards? Please clarify